# Code executes before API response

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, response

I have a function which calls the Google Geocoder API to get latitude and longitude. The problem is that the response comes too late, after the code which depends on the response has executed.

Here Is my current code.

```
var prmList = '';
prmList += '{"Empty":"","Criteria":""}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.pathname + "/GetAddress",
    data: prmList,
    async: false,
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var Alladd = eval('(' + msg.d + ')');
        var itemcount = Alladd.returnAddressList.length;

        if (itemcount > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Street + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].City + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].State + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Country
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            draggable: true,
                            icon: markerImage
                        });

                        markers.push(marker);
                    }
                });
            }

            var zoom = parseInt(-1, 10);
            var size = parseInt(-1, 10);
            var style = parseInt(-1, 10);

            zoom = zoom == -1 ? null : zoom;
            size = size == -1 ? null : size;
            style = style == -1 ? null : style;

            markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                maxZoom: zoom,
                gridSize: size,
                styles: styles[style]
            });
        }
    },

    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Comment: Select your code and hit the `{}` button to format it as code (indented by 4 spaces). You do not need to insert tons of `<br>` tags in there. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Oh, so close. You also don't need tons of `&nbsp;`. Leave one line blank, indent your code by 4 spaces and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

First, please format your code.

Second, what do you mean that your code is executing before the response? If it's dependent on the return of the `$.ajax` call, simply include that function in the `success` continuation.

Ah, I think I see your problem -

Try this:

```
var itemcount = Alladd.returnAddressList.length;
if (itemcount > 0) {                           
    for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Street + "," + <br>Alladd.returnAddressList[i].City + "," + Alladd.returnAddressList[i].State + "," + Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Country
            }, function (results, status) {                                   
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: results[0].geometry.location,
                       draggable: true,
                       icon: markerImage
                });
                markers.push(marker); 
                if(i == itemcount-1)
                {
                    var zoom = parseInt(-1, 10);
                    var size = parseInt(-1, 10);
                    var style = parseInt(-1, 10);
                    zoom = zoom == -1 ? null : zoom;
                    size = size == -1 ? null : size;
                    style = style == -1 ? null : style;               
                    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                    maxZoom: zoom,
                    gridSize: size,
                    styles: styles[style]
               });
              }                                 
                                   }
                               });
                           }

                   }
```

The problem that you're running into is that you're not waiting for all of the async calls to return before running your script. This change ensures that you're on the final expected response before going ahead.

Having said that, you might want to introduce some error checking - what happens if a response isn't returned or you get an error code? Those cases should all be checked.

Comment: so my question is how to stop the execution of code that is written after the Geocoder API Status

Comment: I obviously don't understand. With the change I made to your code, everything from zoom to markClusterer = will not execute until after you receive the last response from google.

Comment: i am getting the response from Gecoder api then if the request status is ok then i am creating a marker and then pushing it to markers array but the response from the API is too slow and the markers array is always 0 because of the response so i want that first i get all the result from the api then insert the result in markers array ad then the remaining code should execute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is synchronous vs. asynchronous code.  Your API requests all result in AJAX (asynchronous) calls being made  — that's why you have to provide the `function(status, response)` callback — but you then immediately (synchronously) try to use the results of those calls, many of which may not have been *made* yet, let alone returned.

What you need to do is delay your `MarkerClusterer` code until after the last API call returns.  The simplest way to do this is to decrement a counter each time a response comes in and fire off the rest of your code when it hits zero.  Note, however, that in this case `markerClusterer` won't be created until after your API calls return, so you may need to add the code which uses it (or better yet, a call to a function which uses it) to the bottom of `createCluster` below.

```
var prmList = '';
prmList += '{"Empty":"","Criteria":""}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.pathname + "/GetAddress",
    data: prmList,
    async: false,
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var Alladd = eval('(' + msg.d + ')');
        var itemcount = Alladd.returnAddressList.length;

        if (itemcount > 0) {
            // createCluster contains all the code which was below the for loop
            function createCluster() {
                var zoom = parseInt(-1, 10);
                var size = parseInt(-1, 10);
                var style = parseInt(-1, 10);

                zoom = zoom == -1 ? null : zoom;
                size = size == -1 ? null : size;
                style = style == -1 ? null : style;

                markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                    maxZoom: zoom,
                    gridSize: size,
                    styles: styles[style]
                });
            }

            for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Street + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].City + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].State + "," +
                               Alladd.returnAddressList[i].Country
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            draggable: true,
                            icon: markerImage
                        });

                        markers.push(marker);
                    }

                    // Decrement the item counter, then check if it's 0.
                    // Using itemcount doesn't screw up the for loop
                    // because this isn't executed until much later!
                    if (!--itemcount) createCluster();
                });
            }

        }
    },

    error: AjaxFailed
});
```